# Is ServiceStack.Redis 3.9.71 compatible with Redis 2.8.X?

Tags: redis, servicestack.redis

3.9.71 is the latest BSD versionned version of ServiceStack.Redis.
But Redis goes on with BSD licenses.

There are merge required changes for redis (2.6.X -> 2.8.X)
https://raw.github.com/antirez/redis/2.8/00-RELEASENOTES

So the question: Could we upgrade Redis to 2.8.X without upgrading ServiceStack.Redis?
(Production environment)

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with servicestack, but since this question is unanswered I thought I would point out something the release notes already tell you: "Redis 2.6 is mostly a strict subset of 2.8". The only change that might break the servicestack client is how certain errors are handled. The rest of the changes shouldn't affect 2.6 clients and should only affect how you use certain redis commands. Seems low risk to set up a test environment with redis 2.8 and see what happens. Pay particular attention to error handling.

Comment: I think as you think. But I will plan to deploy production environment . So we need a little official answer. But thanks for kind response.